# ASP.NET Session keeps on dying

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

I am facing a strange problem with ASP.NET sessions, It keeps on dying every few minutes. I have made changes in web.config still the problem persists.

web.config :

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
   <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
   <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="900"></sessionState>

   <webServices>
     <protocols>
       <add name="HttpPost"/>
       <add name="HttpGet"/>
       <add name="HttpSoap"/>
     </protocols>
  </webServices>

</system.web>
```

I have changed the setting in IIS also. What am i doing wrong? How do I make session endless?

Comment: You use the `InProc`, maybe its time to move it to database. Its natural the InProc to lose their session for some reasons like, they recycle because of too many sites on server full their memory, or the pool recycle.

Comment: @Aristos: can you please give a little hint on moving to database .

Comment: Yes - you run a script that exist on the asp.net directory that creates the database session struct and functions on the SQL server, and then you change the web.config so to been able to use the database. If you look on google there are many tutorials about.